# How to write to server from file line by line?

Tags: java, android

Have seen similar question but no solution. My app saves product information into a txt file "storage.txt". It, temporarily (for debugging), shows the contents of this file into a multiline textview. I'm new to java with some experience in other languages, which I think is causing me to not be able to see the issue here. What I need it to do is read a line from 'storage.txt', upload it to the database, read next line, repeat (if there is a network available). If no network available, overwrite storage with failed uploads. Problem is, when the button is clicked, and network is available, the app crashes.

```
          private void readFromStorage (Context context){
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput("storage.txt");
                if ( inputStream != null ) {
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                    String receiveString = "";
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    //StringBuilder tagBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>(); 

                    while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {

                        stringBuilder.append(receiveString);

                        if(isNetworkAvailable()) {//network found, submit to site and place, do not rewrite to file
                            if (!receiveString.matches("")) {
                                sendToServer(receiveString);
                            }
                        }else{//network not found, rewrite to file
                            if (!receiveString.matches("")) {
                                tags.add(receiveString);
                            }
                        }

                        stringBuilder.append("\n");
                    }
                    inputStream.close();


                    //take new table and write to file, hopefully empty
                    for(int i = 0; i < tags.size(); i++) {
                        String str = tags.get(i).toString();
                        fileRead.append(str);
                        writeToFile(str, context);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
            }
        }

        private void sendToServer (final String sendString){

                if (sendString != null) {

                    String[] separated = sendString.split(";");

                    caliperTXT = separated[0];
                    weightTXT = separated[1];
                    widthTXT = separated[2];
                    typeTXT = separated[3];
                    vendorTXT = separated[4];
                    poTXT = separated[5];
                    aisleTXT = separated[6];
                    plantTXT = separated[7];


                final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, server_url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {

                                builder.setTitle("Server Response");
                                builder.setMessage("Response: " + response);
                                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                    }
                                });
                                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                                alertDialog.show();

                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        Toast.makeText(readStorage.this, "An error has occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        error.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("caliper", caliperTXT);
                        params.put("weight", weightTXT);
                        params.put("width", widthTXT);
                        params.put("type", typeTXT);
                        params.put("vendor", vendorTXT);
                        params.put("po", poTXT);
                        params.put("aisle", aisleTXT);
                        params.put("plant", plantTXT);
                        return params;
                    }
                };

                MySingleton.mInstance(readStorage.this).addTorequestque(stringRequest);
                }
        }
```

Comment: how many lines do you have in your text file?

Comment: Always supply the error log from the logcat when you need help with an error. -- But, to be honest, this looks more like heavy lifting that the server should be doing--not an android device

Comment: text file veries in amount of line, text file is generated when a qr is scanned and no netwrok is found to upload data.

Comment: i didnt consider the server doing the lifting, thanks for the advice, ill give that a shot

Comment: turns out it was just missing 
              builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(readStorage.this);
but I am going to have the server do the work as advised.